# Ionic app won't work properly on device or emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic 1. I have been developing an app where I have used SQLite. It works fine on browser but when I run it on android device or emulator app does not work properly. After I debug I get the below errors:

```
0     009385   error    LiveReload disabled because the browser does not seem to support web sockets
1     009537   log      SELECT * FROM items
2     009552   error    TypeError: Cannot call method 'transaction' of null
    at Object.execute (http://192.168.151.2:8100/js/ng-cordova.min.js:9:23737)
    at new <anonymous> (http://192.168.151.2:8100/js/controllers/salesCtrl.js:51:32)
    at Object.instantiate (http://192.168.151.2:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18015:14)
    at $controller (http://192.168.151.2:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23417:28)
    at [object Object].appendViewElement (http://192.168.151.2:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59908:24)
    at Object.render (http://192.168.151.2:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57901:41)
    at Object.init (http://192.168.151.2:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57821:20)
    at [object Object].render (http://192.168.151.2:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59767:14)
    at [object Object].register (http://192.168.151.2:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59725:10)
    at updateView (http://192.168.151.2:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65400:23), <ion-nav-view name="side-menu21" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="android">
3     009607   error    Uncaught Error: Database location or iosDatabaseLocation setting is now mandatory in openDatabase call., http://192.168.151.2:8100/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js, Line: 565
```

Here is my launcher page code. Where the header icons and title isn't showing on device:

```
angular.module('app.salesCtrl', ['ngCordova'])

    .controller('salesCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$cordovaSQLite', '$ionicPlatform', '$ionicPopup',
        function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $cordovaSQLite, $ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {

            $scope.category = {};
            $scope.categories = ["Food", "Beverages", "Others"];
            $scope.flag = 0;



            $scope.cartPage = function () {

                $state.go('cart');

            }


            $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
                $scope.delete = function () {
                    var query = "delete from items";
                    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function (result) {
                        console.log(result.rows.length);
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log(error);

                    });

                }
            });





            $scope.items = [];




            //EXPERIMENT CODE STARTS 
            //$scope.selectAll = function() {

            //console.log($scope.category.catSelected);



            if (window.cordova) {
                var query = "SELECT * FROM items";
                console.log(query);
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function (res) {

                    if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                        //  console.log("SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(7).itemname + " " + res.rows.item(7).cashier);
                        for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {

                            $scope.items.push({

                                itemname: res.rows.item(i).itemname,
                                price: res.rows.item(i).price,
                                quantity: res.rows.item(i).quantity,
                            });
                            //$scope.items=$scope.items;
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("No results found");
                    }
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error("error=>" + err);
                });
            }
            //EXPERIMENTS CODE ENDS


            //CHANGE SELECT CODE STARTS==========================================


            $scope.showSelectValue = function (mySelect) {


                $scope.items.splice(0, $scope.items.length);


                var query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE category=" + "'" + mySelect + "'";
                console.log(query);
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function (res) {

                    if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                        //  console.log("SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(7).itemname + " " + res.rows.item(7).cashier);
                        for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {

                            $scope.items.push({

                                itemname: res.rows.item(i).itemname,
                                price: res.rows.item(i).price,

                            });

                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("No results found");
                    }
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error("error=>" + err);
                });
                //all


            }



            //CHANGE SELECT CODE ENDS==============================


            //GET QUANTITY STARTS
            $scope.getQuantity = function (item) {

                console.log(item.itemname);

                $scope.data = {};

                // An elaborate, custom popup
                var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
                    template: '<input type="number" ng-model="data.quantity">',
                    title: 'Enter item quantity',
                    subTitle: 'Number of items',
                    scope: $scope,
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: 'Cancel',
                            onTap: function (e) {
                                $scope.flag = 1;
                            }

                        },
                        {
                            text: '<b>Ok</b>',
                            type: 'button-balanced',
                            onTap: function (e) {
                                if (!$scope.data.quantity) {
                                    //don't allow the user to close unless he enters wifi password
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                } else {
                                    return $scope.data.quantity;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });

                myPopup.then(function (res) {
                    console.log("RES IS " + res);
                    if (res != undefined) {
                        //EXPERIMENT CODE STARTS

                        var query = "UPDATE items SET quantity =" + "'" + res + "'" + " WHERE itemname=" + "'" + item.itemname + "' AND price=" + "'" + item.price + "'";
                        console.log(query);
                        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function (result) {


                            console.log("Updated " + res);

                        }, function (err) {
                            console.error("error=>" + err);
                        });

                        //EXPERIMENT CODE ENDS
                        console.log('Tapped!', res);

                        //IONIC ALERT STARTS
                        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: 'Item added to the Cart',
                            template: 'click Ok to see Cart',
                            buttons: [

                                {
                                    text: '<b>Ok</b>',
                                    type: 'button-balanced',


                                }
                            ]


                        });

                        alertPopup.then(function (res) {
                            console.log('Done');


                        });

                    } else {
                        console.log("Cancelled");
                    }
                    //IONIC ALERT ENDS



                });



            }




            //GET QUANTITY ENDS





        }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, `db` variable in never initialised. That is why you have a null exception : `TypeError: Cannot call method 'transaction' of null`

You should do something like this to initisalise the database :

`var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" });`

And do not forget to add the plugin with :

`cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage`

The doc is here :
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/